# Parsing Text, Assigning Variable, Updating Variable

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to take a number of text files, parse them, find the largest number after a certain regular expression and put that into a variable.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
$txt_file = file_get_contents('files/11042013_300_active_users.log');
$rows = explode("\n", $txt_file);

$array_size = sizeof($rows);

for($i=0; $i < $array_size; $i++){
    echo $rows[$i];
    echo "<br />";
}

$max_user = 0;

for($i=0; $i < $array_size; $i++){
    if(preg_match("cnt=", $rows[$i])){
        $max_user++;
    }

}

echo $max_user;
```

The files I want to look in are regular text files. Here is an example of what is inside:

```
11/04/13 07:51:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=1
11/04/13 08:06:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=1
11/04/13 08:21:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=1
11/04/13 08:36:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=1
11/04/13 08:51:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=2
11/04/13 09:06:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=5
11/04/13 09:21:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=5
11/04/13 09:36:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=2
11/04/13 09:51:14 +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+= total cnt=2
```

I am interested in finding the largest integer after "cnt=" for each line.

Based on my code above, I keep getting 0 for $max_users. I don't believe I'm using the preg_match function correctly.

What is the best function to use in order to search an array based on a regular expression ("cnt="), and grab what comes directly after (the integer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished without using a regex. You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) to find the position of `cnt=` string, then use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) to get everything after it (which, in this case, is what you want), and add the values into an array. Once the loop finishes execution, you can simply grab the largest value from the array using [`max()`](http://php.net/max) function.

```
$values = array();
for($i=0; $i < $array_size; $i++){
    // 4 is the length of the string 'cnt='
    $values[] = (int) substr($rows[$i], strpos($rows[$i], 'cnt=') + 4);
}

$max_user = max($values); // get the largest value from the array
echo $max_user; // => 5
```

Now, to answer your original question:

> Based on my code above, I keep getting 0 for $max_users. I don't believe I'm using the preg_match function **correctly**.

You aren't. The regular expression needs to be wrapped in valid delimiters and you're not having one in your code. Also, even if there was one, it wouldn't work, because you're only checking if the line contains `cnt=` string -- which will be true for all the lines in this case.

You need to use capturing groups in your regular expression. For example:

```
if (preg_match("/cnt=(\d+)$/", $rows[$i], $matches)) {
    // $matches[1] contains only what's captured by the first parenthesis
    // which in this case, is the digit after 'cnt='

    // code to store the result in a variable and do the processing ...
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks Amal! It works perfectly. Thanks for the in-depth explanation too!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple change:

```
if(preg_match("/cnt=(\d+)$/", $rows[$i], $matches)){
    if ($matches[1] > $max_user) {
       $max_user = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Capture the digit(s) after `cnt`, and keep track of which one was largest.

Comment: you need a delimiter on the regex ;) `/cnt=(\d+)$/`

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm still not getting it to work. Why are you indexing the 2nd item in the $matches array by using "1"?

Comment: @markmilly: $matches[0] is always the entire string that triggered the match. the capture groups `(...)` always start at index 1 in the captures array.